# substring by C language function of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to creat a c-language function for postgresql which returns a substring of a given string

```
 Datum pg_string_slice(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    text* original_text = PG_GETARG_TEXT_P(0);
    int64 start = PG_ARGISNULL(1) ? 0 : PG_GETARG_INT64(1);
    if (VARDATA(original_text) == nullptr)
    {
        PG_RETURN_NULL();
    }
    // Length = buffer size (format [valena type]) - header size (VARHDRSZ)
    // The size of the buffer is saved in the header (start of the buffer [4 bytes]).
    const int64 string_length = VARSIZE(original_text) - VARHDRSZ;
    int64 stop = PG_ARGISNULL(2) ? string_length : PG_GETARG_INT64(2);
    text* result = (text*)palloc(string_length + VARHDRSZ);
    uint64 new_length;
.
.
.
    //using here memcpy for transfering the substring to the palloced memory
.
.
.
    SET_VARSIZE(result, new_length + VARHDRSZ);
    PG_RETURN_TEXT_P(result);
}
```

is there a way I can return the sub string without having to allocate a buffer and just manipulate the given string some how?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to allocate space.  The `text` argument is immutable – for example, it might be a reference to a value in a TOAST table. A `text` starts with a header that contains the size of the value, so you wouldn't be able to use the same memory for your purposes without changing it.

Don't forget to de-TOAST the value.